# Date this Jubilee Day photo

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, 1940s, 1950s

I participate in a Facebook group about the history of my hometown, Mechanicsburg, PA.  We are trying to put a year on the following picture taken on the town’s annual street fair, called Jubilee Day.

[image]

Because Jubilee Day is always held on a Thursday, we already know that it was either 1947, 1952, 1958, or 1969.  Because of the 48 star flag, and the kids clothes and hair, we know it wasn’t 1969.

What I am hoping is that someone with more knowledge of the period dress and styles can pin it down further.

The other big possible clue are the two vehicles in the upper right corner.  The bus is unobscured and looks very distinctive to me, so if anybody could identify its model and make, that would probably do it.

Here’s a blowup of the vehicles.

[image]

Comment: I assume the buildings were in existence throughout the period 1947-1958, and so give no evidence?

Comment: Not so far.  The large buildings were there forever. The two smaller buildings behind the bus I am trying to find out about.

Comment: FYI, I am almost certain now that the bus is a Flexible Clipper.

Comment: I can only go by British fashion norms, which might have been more formal than American, but judging from the women's clothes - no hats, no gloves, bare arms - I'd suspect later in your time period. (Growing up in the '50s, I rarely remember my mother going out without a hat/headscarf, and we were working class.) Can the local newspaper archives help?

Comment: Hmm, actually, the bus could have also been an early Flxble Visicoach, which succeeded the Clipper, so not much help there unless I can figure out which.

Comment: @TheHonRose Not sure about that, different country and all.  Also Jubilee Day is notoriously hot and a couple hours on the macadam might discourage ladies headgear.

Comment: Ok, I am now pretty sure that the bus is a Flxible Clipper and not a Visicoach from the Flxible owners site.  The last year they were made was 1950 and since there’s no destination plate on the front I assume that it is either a show model or privately owned.  Based on its location, I think it on the plaza/sidewalk, not in a parking lot so that would mean it’s on display, which should make it new.  I think that should make this then no later than 1951.

Comment: You're probably right - *mad dogs and Englishmen* ;)

Comment: You might be able to contact the Boy Scout troop 90 asking when they were founded. (I don't see this info on their [web-site](https://sites.google.com/site/bsatroop90foresthills/) .)

Comment: This is no help but the (bank?) building on the right reminds me of a bank in Jenkintown, PA.

Comment: Since this is now a collective hunt: do we make this one a community wiki or an extra chat? I have some hints that while altogether inconclusive are of a little certainty for some aspects;  too long for comments but too weak for an answer?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: this picture is looking east on Main Street from a point just west of Market?

Comment: How about the shop names on the left?  I see "Biddle's" and "...LCO" with writing below it I can't make out.   If you have a street directory and if any of the businesses changed, you have a chance.  But I imagine Biddle's was always there.

Comment: @kimchilover Biddles was there from 1910-1987.  The other I don't know, we're seeing if anyone remembers.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes.  Are you familiar with it?

Comment: Can you make out the writing on the placard to the "south east" of the Biddles sign?  Another possible clue: I seem to see a PA 14 (?) highway sign on the right side of the street, more or less opposite Biddles, where nowadays you might expect a 641 sign.  I've never been in Mechanicsburg, but want to make sure I'm using Google Maps & streetview correctly.

Comment: @kimchilover I have not been able to, no.

Comment: @LangLangC I would be OK with making it a community wiki if the moderators think that's appropriate.

Comment: Have you tried to recognise the people? The kids could be around 60-70 now, maybe someone recognises their parents, aunts, neighbours. That could help to narrow down the time frame.

Comment: @Marzipanherz No hits yet.  One possible, but they're not sure.

Comment: Sure looks like 1958 to me; I remember going to events like this back then.

Answer (score 6):

The many cues to observe:

## Picture quality

Although it might be even higher resolution and a better scan: depth of field, focus, shadows etc point to an overall technology that's more late than sooner.

## The vehicles

[image]
RBarryYoung: Ok, I am now pretty sure that the bus is a Flxible Clipper and not a Visicoach from the Flxible owners site. The last year they were made was 1950 and since there’s no destination plate on the front I assume that it is either a show model or privately owned. Based on its location, I think it on the plaza/sidewalk, not in a parking lot so that would mean it’s on display, which should make it new. I think that should make this then no later than 1951.

## Drawn carriages

### a baby carriage

[image]

apparently a Columbia Tuk-A-Way
For comparison:

[image: From an auction on ebay]

Source: [VTG 1950's Columbia TUK-A-WAY Baby Stroller Westfield Mfg MOTHER Children's Ad](https://www.ebay.com/itm/VTG-1950s-Columbia-TUK-A-WAY-Baby-Stroller-Westfield-Mfg-MOTHER-Childrens-Ad-/352126673104)
Earliest date of manufacture? (If newspaper ads confirm that its 1954?)
Note that it has been patented. Date for the patent?
kimchilover: The Tuk-A-Way dates to 1955 or earlier: see this 1955 ad, for instance: aditorial in [Life Magazine](https://books.google.de/books?id=RVYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=tuk-a-way%20stroller&source=bl&ots=7pwmeEFe8U&sig=1pCryGbSsF1uUbVi-tQaSzkTlb0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=tuk-a-way%20stroller&f=false)  20 Jun 1955
Describing the cart as an innovation from "in the last two years" (but there seem to have been sturdier versions of the cart in question and "last two years" is imprecise and might mean publication date minus 2,99 years")
An earlier dated Photo is [1954 PRESS PHOTO TUK-A-WAY](https://outlet.historicimages.com/products/nee33391), using the same source material for a collage as the VTG picture.

### another baby carriage?

[image]

## The boyscouts:

[image]
When were they founded?
What is this font, exactly?

## T-shirt boy

[image]
When did it became acceptable, when mainstream to wear this in public?

(mid 50s?)

## The street lamps

[image]
Distinctive style, introduced when, exchanged when?

## The shop names

[image]
An "*.*._LCO" and "Biddle's" sign.
When were they active, in that location?

## Fashionable sun glasses

[image]
A lady with what appears to be cat's eye glasses -> mid 50s

## Fashionable socks and naked shoulders

[image]

A lady exposing her shoulders and a boy wearing quite sloppy socks and (sneakers)? 
-> late 50s

## More naked shoulders

[image]

## Madame couture

[image]

The most fashionable lady yet.
Trousers, relatively tight, with slits, also in bobby socks, flat shoes, rolled up sleeves.  Might be [Capri pants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capri_pants):

> Capri pants were introduced by fashion designer Sonja de Lennart in 1948. The name of the pants is derived from the Italian isle of Capri, where they rose to popularity in the late 1950s and early '60s
>   -> mid to late 50s

## Miniskirt girl

Quite an outlier for the rest of the scene:
[image]
a girl in what has to be identified as a miniskirt? That complicates things substantially.

> [Hemlines were just above the knee in 1961, and gradually climbed upward over the next few years. By 1966, some designs had the hem at the upper thigh. Stockings with suspenders were not considered practical with miniskirts and were replaced with coloured tights. The popular acceptance of miniskirts peaked in the "Swinging London" of the 1960s, and has continued to be commonplace, particularly among younger women and teenage girls. Before that time, short skirts were only seen in sport and dance clothing, such as skirts worn by female tennis players, figure skaters, cheerleaders, and dancers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniskirt)

## Current situation

An approximation of the location with Google Earth:
[image]

Compared to the above: the church has now a different top:
[image]

On the old picture there is a spire missing. when was that done?

Edit:  According to [this](http://cumberlink.com/news/local/history/new-book-details-history-of-churches-in-mechanicsburg/article_a65be48a-9a6d-11e4-b62a-577b6fb7a819.html) site, the steeple was changed in 1978, so no help there:

> In 1978, The First Church of God, 28 E. Main St., Mechanicsburg, was receiving its new 4-ton, 42-foot-long steeple, which came into town on a flatbed tractor-trailer.

## Current conclusion:

The vehicles might be a bit outdated, the women's fashion seem to firmly rule out late 40s and early 50s.

---

Sources:
For fashion info:
[Vintage Socks | 1920s, 1930s, 1940s, 1950s, 1960s History](https://vintagedancer.com/vintage/history-of-vintage-womens-socks/)
[1940s Swing Pants & Sailor Trousers- Wide Leg, High Waist](https://vintagedancer.com/1940s/womens-1940s-style-pants/)
[1940s Style Skirts- Vintage High Waisted Skirts](http://1940s%20Style%20Skirts-%20Vintage%20High%20Waisted%20Skirts)
[1940s Style Hats](https://vintagedancer.com/1940s/vintage-inspired-1940s-hats-for-ladies/)
[1950s Dresses, 50s Dresses | Swing, Wiggle, Pin Up Dresses](https://vintagedancer.com/1950s/1950s-style-dresses/)
[1950s 50s Costumes- Poodle Skirts, Grease, Monroe, Pin up, I Love Lucy](https://vintagedancer.com/1950s/1950s-costumes-for-sale/)
[1950s Swing Skirt, Poodle Skirt, Pencil Skirts](https://vintagedancer.com/1950s/1950s-skirts/)
[1950s Housewife Dress | 50s Day Dresses](https://vintagedancer.com/1950s/1950s-housewife-dress/)

[A concise illustrated history of Women’s Fashion and Style – 1940 to 1949 –](http://glamourdaze.com/history-of-womens-fashion/1940-to-1949)
[50s wardrobes](http://glamourdaze.com/category/1950s-wardrobe)
[40s Women's Clothing](https://www.uvm.edu/landscape/dating/clothing_and_hair/1940s_clothing_women.php)
[50s Women's Clothing](https://www.uvm.edu/landscape/dating/clothing_and_hair/1950s_clothing_women.php)

Comment: thanks, good stuff. Biddles was there from 1910-1987. The other I don't know, we're seeing if anyone remembers.  The girls hemline is misleading I think, because the rules for immature girls were always considerably different than for mature girls and young women.  The picture quality is exceptional, but I think that people tend to underestimate how high the quality of old B+W professional photos were.  (I am more impressed with how good the conversion/scanning was for this).

Comment: The capri(?) style pants struck me also, I thought that they might be a real bellweather for pinning down the year.  Any specific references for them?

Comment: I was wondering about the baby carriages too, they seemed like they might be dateable.

Comment: If someone might point out (with an edit) which flag is supposed to be non50 stars? I do not see it as clearly.

Comment: Its evident on all of the flags with discernable stars, but the clearest is the central one, hanging from the pole pointing at an angle into the the center of the photo.  Even though you cannot see all of the stars, if you compare it to all of the flags of the 20th century, it's clear that there is only one it could be.  The 48-star flag was the only one with the stars laid out in a rectilinear grid (6x8) which these are.  All other flags close to this time period had the stars in staggered offset rows (as our current 50-star flag does).

Comment: As for the T-shirts, everyone I thought might be one (including the boy above) turned out to have a faint pattern on them (the boy's, for example has a faint diamond cross-hatch pattern), so I think that they are actually print pull-over shirts.  Though I agree that t-shirts would be strong evidence for the late 50's.

Comment: Re: flag. I see that pattern now, on 1 or 2 of them. The others are too blurry) But how common was it to fly a slightly outdated flag? ("Marge: Grandpa, why are there only 49 stars on that flag? Grandpa: It’ll be a cold day in hell before I recognize Missourah!")

Comment: This is a civic affair run by a conservative town hall and Chamber of Commerce, as long as they had at least a few months notice, there's no way they wouldn't have the right flags.

Comment: So, by elimination, it would be 1958, no?

Answer (score 2):

It was taken about 1970, if you believe The Pram Museum, since the baby stroller in the right foreground is a [Columbia Tuk-A-Way](http://www.prammuseum.com/strollers70.html) (USA manufacturer).

Although, [here's an ad](https://topcatprintads.ecrater.com/p/5299832/1954-columbia-tuk-a-way-baby-stroller) for the same stroller reportedly offered in 1954. From the auto in the photo, that seems likley.

Comment: The Tuk-A-Way dates to 1955 or earlier: see 
 this 1955 ad, for instance:  https://books.google.com/books?id=RVYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=tuk-a-way+stroller&source=bl&ots=7pwmeEFe8U&sig=1pCryGbSsF1uUbVi-tQaSzkTlb0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK467J6LLZAhWxtVkKHU52Dg8Q6AEIVDAM#v=onepage&q=tuk-a-way%20stroller&f=false

Comment: Yes, you beat me to the correction.

Comment: Thx for finding the make of the stroller. But date of introduction of a class of items and date of manufacture of a particular item and service life of that item are three different things.

Comment: Here is another 1954 source: https://outlet.historicimages.com/products/nee33391  It ran in the April 5 1954 issue of Life magazine.

Comment: If the Tuk was introduced in 1954 then the Jubillee would have to 1958, *since "Because Jubilee Day is always held on a Thursday, we already know that it was either 1947, 1952, 1958, or 1969. Because of the 48 star flag, and the kids clothes and hair, we know it wasn’t 1969"*

Comment: ***If***. That is to be confirmed now. "during the last two years"" in the one article…

Comment: The search term "tuck-a-way stroller" got a hit on google books for the 1955 US Patent Office Gazette, (vol 692) with this summary:  " The Westfield Manufacturing Company, West- fleld, Mass. Filed Feb. 2, 1954. tuk-a WAY For Folding Strollers for Children. Use since Nov. 30, 1953. SN 665,206."

Comment: As for Westfield: look at the bottom part of the ad: Westfield was the firm, Columbia was its brand name.  As for Google: I entered the terms into the search box, clicked the "more" option box, chose "books", and got some hits.  The text I posted was from the summary  list of results: Google does not give out electronic versions of the Gazette.  I am not skilled enough   to find it on the USPTO web site.

Comment: @kimchilover I did the same, GBooks doesn't show. Gazette is [here](https://archive.org/details/officialgazette692unit)?

Comment: A patent registration date will bear only earliest date, the widest distribution date is more valuable. That’s why I would rank the Life ad campaign to be the beginning of that point.

Comment: The 1953 patent in the gazette  thing is just the trademark and logo registered. Have now seen some very strange drawings for patents of that time (fold away with child still inside…) but this thing seems to consist of a string of individual patents…?

Comment: LangLangC, thanks for the internet archive thing.  The trademark application is on what my viewer says is p87 (of 992 in all), on "March 1, 1955", page TM 10.  The complete text is "SN 660,519. The Westfield Manufacturing Company, Westfield, Mass. Filed Feb. 2, 1954.  TUK-A-WAY For Folding Strollers for Children.  Use since Nov. 30, 1953." The words TUK-A-WAY are an image of the logo.  Herb Guy's point is well taken.  This evidence (I think) rules out 1947 and 1952.

Comment: As I suspected from early on based on fashion, 58 is very probable. Unless the other clues do not turn something else up, the stroller is a kicker. – herbguy and @kimchilover: integrate that into the wiki answer (after a little while – woul like to know about the church spire). Although I think herb was a little gun jumping at first (70s…) he did identify the stroller, so deserves the rep here. +1